# How to convert a png into the same input format of tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was following a tutorial to make predictions on fashion items like shoes or t-shirts.
When I use tensorflow's example code it works fine.

The second aim was to save neural network's weights. I also manually pasted them into a file to make sure that when I recall the network with the weights they are correctly reloaded.

After that, my last goal was to make prediction on a 28 x 28 gray png image then I personally stored into my hard drive.

The point is that it gives weird results and does not recognize the object...

I put here the code.

Tensorflow original code adapted to also save neural network's weights.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os as os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(tf.__version__)
fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat','Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
print(train_images[0])

'''DEFINISCO LE DIRECTORY PER SALVARE I PESI '''
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)



train_images = train_images / 255.0

test_images = test_images / 255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
plt.show()


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)



model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, callbacks=[cp_callback])

print(model.layers[1].weights)
print(model.layers[1].bias.numpy())
print(model.layers[1].bias_initializer)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)


probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])

predictions = probability_model.predict(test_images)

np.argmax(predictions[0])


test_labels[0]


def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
  true_label, img = true_label[i], img[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])

  plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
  if predicted_label == true_label:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'red'

  plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                class_names[true_label]),
                                color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
  true_label = true_label[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks(range(10))
  plt.yticks([])
  thisplot = plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
  plt.ylim([0, 1])
  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

  thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
  thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')


# Plot the first X test images, their predicted labels, and the true labels.
# Color correct predictions in blue and incorrect predictions in red.
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 3
num_images = num_rows*num_cols
plt.figure(figsize=(2*2*num_cols, 2*num_rows))
for i in range(num_images):
  plt.subplot(num_rows, 2*num_cols, 2*i+1)
  plot_image(i, predictions[i], test_labels, test_images)
  plt.subplot(num_rows, 2*num_cols, 2*i+2)
  plot_value_array(i, predictions[i], test_labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Then, my partially working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import os as os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
print(tf.__version__)


'''DEFINISCO LE DIRECTORY PER SALVARE I PESI '''
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)



model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

print("\n\n\n\n\nPESI PRIMA DEL CARICAMENTO")
print(model.layers[1].weights)
print(model.layers[1].bias.numpy())
print(model.layers[1].bias_initializer)

model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
print("\n\n\n\nPESI DOPO IL CARICAMENTO")
print(model.layers[1].weights)
print(model.layers[1].bias.numpy())
print(model.layers[1].bias_initializer)


model.summary()




image = image.imread('test2.png')

file_uno = open("esempio_uno.txt", "w")


# summarize shape of the pixel array

print(image.dtype)

print(image.shape)

# display the array of pixels as an image

plt.imshow(image)

plt.show()
data = np.asarray(image)
#print(data)
data = data / 255.0
data = data.flatten(order='F')

file_uno.write(np.array2string(data))
file_uno.close()

end = int((len(data)/4))
data = data[0:end]
print(len(data))

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67839110/tensorflowmodel-was-constructed-with-shape-none-28-28-but-it-was-called-o


data = np.reshape(data, (1, 28, 28))

data2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img("test2.png")

print(data2)

predictions = model.predict(data2, 1)
print(predictions)
inputt = input()
```

I suspect that the problem is strongly related with the format of the png file. In some way, I do not convert it properly into a vector.
Can you help me?

Comment: What "weird result" is it giving? No one can solve your problem unless you give specific information on what exactly is going wrong. What are you getting when you do `print(data2)`?

Comment: The output of data2 is <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=28x28 at 0x20DC401F5B0>, while the output of data (which is the other attempt as input I made) is a linearized matrix of 28x28 reporting values values from 0 to 1.

The output of the prediction is in this second case (the only working):

[[ -7.683368  -21.710634  -15.393627  -15.403307  -18.675303   -2.5988886
  -11.572779  -17.607311  -17.004343  -26.49455  ]]

TensorFlow's example outputs are small number included in the range [0, 1]